# How to call a function from index.html to app.js file in node js application javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I had a node js application where I have my app.js and one html which gets displayed for the route /index.Now In my index file I had a button and text box and when I click button Iam trying to call a function.Where in that function I will have a variable with some text "Hello" which should be displayed in text box.I couldnt achieve this can some one help.

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="jumbotron"  style="padding:40px;">
<h1>Hello!!!</h1>
<div>
<button type="submit" onclick="getData();">Call</button>
<input type="text">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
app.get('/index',function(req,res){ 
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html'));
});
function getData(){
console.log("Hello");
var text="Hello";
};
```

Right now Im getting reference error that getData is not defined.Can someone help over here.

Comment: You need to move `getData` to your client side js file or just include it in `script` tags in html.

Comment: @NenadVracar got it...One question how can we add that function in client side js file...I mean how can we call that js file..

Comment: Iam calling my html from server side app.js

Comment: You just create your client js file in same directory where your `index.html` file is and include it `<script src="fileName.js"></script>` or you can write your js code inside `<script></script>` tags in html file which is not recommended. Also in your app.js file you need to specify where your static files are using `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'PathHere')));

Comment: function in <script></script> tags worked...But when I tried to call the js as u mentioned but it didnt worked.It is giving me
GET http://localhost:3000/index.js 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Are you using express?

Comment: yes Iam using express

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138097/discussion-between-user7350714-and-nenad-vracar).

Comment: Create new folder where your app.js file is called `public` and put your index.html and client side js file for example `main.js`, and then in your app.js file add this `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`

Comment: It worked now...

Comment: @NenadVracar How about if I need to call a rest call which is present in my server side js file from my client side when I click that button?Is it possible?

Comment: Give me an example?

Comment: @NenadVracar The scenario is this..I have a jar file and Iam running that using (child_process).exec and getting the result in to one variable.This is all done in my server side app.js..Now I need to display that variable in my client side textarea on click of that button

var exec = require('child_process').exec;
 var child = exec('java -jar ./helloworld.jar',
 function (error, stdout, stderr){
    console.log('Output -> ' + stdout);
    jardata=stdout;
    console.log(jardata,"jar out...");
    if(error !== null){
      console.log("Error -> "+error);}});
module.exports = child;

Answer (score 2):

**index.html** runs in browser so you can't call `getData()` function that is defined on server side in `app.js`

Move `getData()` function body to `index.html` as Nenad Vracar suggests or use some kind of API for client-server communication.

**code moved to index.html**

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
    function getData() {
        var text="Hello";
        document.querySelector('#input_id').value = text;
    }
</script>
<div class="jumbotron"  style="padding:40px;">
    <h1>Hello!!!</h1>
    <div>
        <button type="submit" onclick="getData();">Call</button>
        <input type="text" id="input_id">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok..got it I had 2 questions how to make that var text displayed in input box onclick of button..Other how can I create client side js file to add that function in it.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may have misunderstood what NodeJS is. Node isn't like other JavaScript or jQuery that runs in the browser.

Node is code that runs on the server. What you've correctly done in your `app.js` is have the server send the `index.html` file to the browser. But after that point all that the browser knows about and has access to is the `index.html` file, it is a separate file and context and so has no access to the server anymore.

The only way to have your page call a function on the server would be to create some sort of API where your page sends a separate http request to the server, which then responds with the function's output.