# how to set html elements values using node.js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I created a node.js connection to my mysql database, and I am able to retrieve and input data to my database using `connection.query()`. Now I wan't to be able to show the data on my database on my html elements values, is there something like `getElementBtID`. I have no idea how to do it because I'm new to back end development.

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42806949/how-to-call-a-function-from-index-html-to-app-js-file-in-node-js-application-jav

Answer (score 0):

You can render the html server side with something like 'handlebars' or 'pug'.